# MongoDB find in nested array aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have nested array documents explained below:

```
countries: [
  {
    "id": "id of country",
    "cities": [
      {
        "id": "id of city 1",
        "areas": [
          {
            "id": "id of area 1"
          },
          {
            "id": "id of area 2"
          },
          {
            "id": "id of area 3"
          },
          {
            "id": "id of area 4"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "id of city 2",
        "areas": [
          {
            "id": "id of area 1"
          },
          {
            "id": "id of area 2"
          },
          {
            "id": "id of area 3"
          },
          {
            "id": "id of area 4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My target is to add a field using `$addFields` to indicate if a given id matching area ID or not.

```
{$addFields: {
    isDeliveringToArea: {
      $in: [ObjectId('5db5d11cb18a2500129732a5'),'$countries.cities.areas.id']
    } 
}}
```

but apparently `$in` doesn't work with nested arrays.
I want something like the find method works `Model.find({'countries.cities.areas.id': 'areaID'})` but to return a boolean value in the aggregation.

Comment: @turivishal in the pipeline aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 3 level nested arrays, we can achieve this with `$map` which is used to run all/modify the objects. First `$map` used to go through each **country** object, the second `$map` used to go each **city** objects inside each **country** object

**Update 1**

Since you need over all filed, you can do it with `$anyElementTrue` which helps if there is any element true on our condition, it will emit **true**.

**Working [Mongo play ground for overall country](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J-jBLbTARzK)**

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      isDeliveringToArea: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
          $map: {
            input: "$countries",
            in: {
              $anyElementTrue: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$$this.cities",
                  in: {
                    $in: [
                      "6",
                      "$$this.areas.id"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I keep the old query for your reference.
Working [Mongo playground for each country object](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vNJHm2s99GF)

Comment: thanks, @varman for the help, but I need to add isDeliveringToArea to the main documents, not to every element in countries, similar to this [{id: 1, countries: [...], isDeliveringToArea: true }, {id: 2, countries: [...], isDeliveringToArea: false}]